# How to propagate errors from multiple threads in rust?

Tags: multithreading, logging, error-handling, rust

In a Rust application that is:

- Synchronous in the sense of not using "async"
- multi-threaded using std::thread
- threads are communicating via channels
- the "anyhow" crate is being used to annotate and propagate Results

I am propagating all errors up to the main thread, but I only see the Error that is hit by the main thread. This usually happens before I join the child threads, so I don't see the actual root cause.

What minimum-boilerplate modification can I make to see the Errors from multiple threads?

(I'll put some ideas I have in answers, but I'm hoping there is something better.)

Comment: What you're asking is really quite unclear, what do you mean by "the error that is hit by the main thread", does you main thread error before it even finds out whether child threads errored? `join` on the child thread should return an Err if the thread panicked, otherwise it will return whatever the thread returned, so if your threads return Results when they terminate you should be able to collect these and manage them however you want. Basically your `joins` would return `Result<Result<(), ThreadError>, PanicError>`.

Comment: Update: I found Vec<Result>.collect(), but that only returns the first error. If I understand correctly, the same thing prevents me from chaining Result::and() and Result:and_then.

Comment: @Masklinn I do in fact do a bit more in my main thread, since I saw no reason not to, but I can move that into a child thread too for uniformity, and declare it the supervisor patern. however, I still don't know how to join all the threads cleanly.

Comment: Yes `collect()`-ing to a Result only returns the first failure. And `and_then` is focused on the "success path", for the "failure path" you want `or_else`, though in this case it's not really useful: you'd need a synthetic acting as the collector for all your failures. Just iterate on the child threads and shove the `Err` values in a vec (possibly with some conversions if you want to keep the `panic` errs as well as the return-value errs).

Answer (score 0):

I could use my main thread only for supervising child threads, aggregate all of their Results in some kind of Vec as I join them, filter it, and write custom code to print it.

This still feels like more work than should be necessary; I'm not the first person to write a threaded rust application that handles errors.

Comment: This sounds about right, having a supervisor thread and a bunch of worker threads is the standard pattern for that sort of things. Having the supervisor also be a worker sounds extremely odd. And you can aggregate during collection, just don't add the `Ok(Ok(_))` information in the collected output, if you end up with a non-empty result set, at least one thread failed. As to "custom code to print it", that pretty much just `print!("{:?}", error)`.

Answer (score 0):

I could let threads panic and "propagate the panics":

https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/thread/type.Result.html

But this is ugly:

- It introduces a difference between how errors are handled in child threads vs. the main thread.
- At every fallible call site in my original code I have to add .unwrap().
- If I unwrap() every error in the child threads, I might as well not even be using Result error handling, because everything will be returning Ok() or panicking. If I make that transformation, then I change the signature of all my existing functions, which is also gross.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to upgrade the entire application to use a logging framework, and then scrape through the logs.

This will require modifications everywhere have added an anyhow .context(), ensure!, or bail! annotation, to conditionally also throw a logger error.

Eventually I will want both logging/telemetry and clean teardown from propagating Results, but even then I will not want to have several lines of boilerplate for every single fallible function call.